# Joi validate union type

Tags: node.js, typescript, joi

I have union type `PaymentTerm`:

```js
type PaymentTerm =
    | { type: 'AdvancePayment' }
    | { type: 'PaymentGoal'; netPaymentDays: number }
```

I want to validate it using `Joi.alternatives`:

```
  Joi.object({
    type: Joi.string().required().valid('AdvancePayment')
  }),
  Joi.object({
    type: Joi.string().required().valid('PaymentGoal'),
    netPaymentDays: Joi.number().required().messages({
      'any.required': '{{#label}} is required'
    })
  })
)

const { error, value } = schema.validate({
  type: 'PaymentGoal'
})
```

Now I would expect to get `"netPaymentDays" is required` but I get `"value" does not match any of the allowed types`.

How can I get the "nested" errors instead of the generic ones for the alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

You've mentioned the correct way to resolve this but I can't see it being used in your example.

> I want to validate it using `Joi.alternatives`

A possible solution for your schema would be:

```
Joi.object().keys({
    type: Joi.string().valid('AdvancePayment', 'PaymentGoal').required(),
    netPaymentDays: Joi.alternatives().conditional('type', {
        is: 'PaymentGoal',
        then: Joi.number().required(),
        otherwise: Joi.forbidden()
    })
});
```